# Dll файли и их размещения

Tags: qt, c++, dll

Здравствуйте, у меня есть проект на c++ qt. Когда я делаю релиз и запускаю exe-шник выскакивает ошибка, которая требует dll с qt. Я перемещаю нужные dll в папку с программой. В результате, куча файлов в одной папке. Могу ли я и КАК организовать иерархию файлов типа:

```
-папка с программой
--сам exe-шник
--папка с dll
---файлы dll
```

Comment: да, если папка с dll будет в PATH.

Comment: @KoVadim, а если я не хочу прописывать в Path? например, портативное приложения.

Comment: создайте себе батник, который поправит PATH и запустит программу. На другие программы это не повлияет.

Comment: @KoVadim, но теоретически и в начале программы до вызова qt методов, я могу добавить в Path

Comment: Если dll подключаются динамически, то можно использовать относительные пути. При статическом подключении в QtCreator не знаю как будет работать. А кутэшные библиотеки можно включить в exe если что.

Comment: Включить можно, только если у Вас комерческая лицензия.

Исправить Path в коде можно, но не для всех dll. Для части все равно придется править PATH.